# Is there a way to unlock higher graphics settings?

Tags: heroes-of-the-storm

I'm playing HOTS on my laptop, which has an integrated Intel card and an NVIDIA card. The game runs fine, automatically using the NVIDIA card, and the performance is great.

However, in the graphics settings menu, only the Intel card is listed, which locks some of the higher graphics settings, specifically the texture quality.

Is there a way to resolve this, perhaps by modifying some config files?

Comment: You can try some of the things from these forums: https://eu.battle.net/forums/en/heroes/topic/17615002256 https://us.forums.blizzard.com/en/heroes/t/game-isnt-recognizing-graphics-card/11961 https://community.amd.com/thread/212374. If none of it works then it's a HOTS bug.

Answer (score 2):

I’m almost sure that this issue is regarding the driver of your Nvidia video card.

Since settings detection is inherited from the Operating System, then If Heroes of the storm doesn’t “see” your card it’s because your Operating System is having difficulties to recognize the video card.

I would recommend you to reinstall the driver from the Nvidia page. You can search for your graphic card here. Or if you don’t know the exact model I would recommend you to look for it on the official website of the manufacturer.

Install the driver, and restart your system, that should fix the recognition issue for your graphic card.

Comment: I've updated and reinstalled the driver multiple times, to no avail. I've never had this sort of problem with other modern or even semi-modern games